# primefaces jsf EventBus onMessage not shown

Tags: ajax, primefaces, jsf-2, atmosphere

i'm implementing push notif using primefaces and jsf i tried this code but the notif  i imlpemented NotifyResource like this

```
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;

import org.primefaces.push.annotation.OnMessage;

import org.primefaces.push.annotation.PushEndpoint;

import org.primefaces.push.impl.JSONEncoder;

@PushEndpoint("/notify")

public class NotifyResource {

 @OnMessage(encoders = { JSONEncoder.class })

 public FacesMessage onMessage(FacesMessage message) {

 return message;
 }
}
```

but the notification is not shown

```
<h:body>

 <p:growl widgetVar="growl" showDetail="true" />

 <h:form>
  <h:panelGrid columns="2">
   <p:outputLabel for="summary" value="Summary: " />
   <p:inputText id="summary" value="#{notifyView.summary}"
    required="true" />

   <p:outputLabel for="detail" value="Detail: " />
   <p:inputText id="detail" value="#{notifyView.detail}" required="true" />
  </h:panelGrid>

  <p:commandButton value="Send" actionListener="#{notifyView.send}" />
 </h:form>

 <p:socket onMessage="handleMessage" channel="/notify" />

 <script type="text/javascript">
        function handleMessage(facesmessage) {
            facesmessage.severity = 'info';

            PF('growl').show([facesmessage]);
        }
 </script>
</h:body>
</html>
```

can any one help me? i'm using primefaces 6.0 and atmosphere 2.4.0

Comment: Have you declared PrimeFaces Push servlet and its mapping in `web.xml`?

Comment: Also, can you share the code, where you are publishing data to `EventBus`.

Comment: yes I have declared Push servant in web.xml

Comment: this is function used for. publishing data.       public void send() {
        EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();
        eventBus.publish(CHANNEL, new FacesMessage(StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml3(summary), StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml3(detail)));
    }

Comment: Any exception observed in logs or server startup regarding PrimeFaces push or atmosphere?

Comment: Basically, I was also observing some issues with atmosphere-2.4.0 and prior with PrimeFaces 5.3. Try using 2.4.2 of atmosphere with 1 version of javax.inject.

Comment: no exception  thnx I will try